Why does Flutter DevTools Network tab record responses with HTTP 304 code?
I'm using Flutter DevTools to monitor network activity in my Flutter app. I've noticed that the Network tab records responses with the HTTP status code 304 Not Modified. These responses are typically cached and don't contain a response body.
However, in my current setup:

The API responses with 304 are still being logged in the DevTools.
I expected DevTools to ignore these responses since no new data is being transferred.

Here are my questions:

Why does Flutter DevTools log 304 responses? Is this expected behavior?
Is there a way to filter out these 304 responses in DevTools or in the app configuration to reduce noise during debugging?

For reference:

I'm using Flutter version 3.22.2.
Network requests are made using Dio or another specific package.

